# Best Practices for passing parameters between functions?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell function i created to deploy our stored procedures:

```
Function Deploy-Procedures {
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory=$true)] 
        [string[]] $files,
        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory=$true)] 
        [string] $databaseServer,
        [Parameter(Position = 2, Mandatory=$true)] 
        [string] $databaseName,
        [string] $databaseUserName,
        [string] $databasePassword,
        [byte] $numRetries = 2
    )
```

Right now this procedure works as standalone. You will noticed the `$files` variable is just a string array. The individual executing the script just passes an array of files to be deployed. I want to create another powershell script that proceduces the list of files that need to be deployed and pipe those to the *Deploy-Procedures* script. I have never dealt with a function that either has to pipe info to another command or has to accept piped info. Is there any best practices to accomplish this? Should the type be changed from string array to something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the output type of the function that generates the list of files.  If that is going to be strings (paths) then you can do this:

```
[Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] 
[ValidateNotNullOrEmtpy()]
[string[]] $Files,
```

If you want your Deploy-Procedures function to work with a list of files generated by Get-ChildItem (or Get-Item) do this:

```
[Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)] 
[Alias("PSPath")]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmtpy()]
[string[]] $Files,
```

I would also recommend renaming the parameter from $files to $Path.  And for other best practices, I PascalCase my advanced function parameters to be consistent with other PowerShell commands.  One last best practice, usually `noun` in PowerShell are singular. Consider calling the function `Deploy-Procedure`.